# Wordpress homepage change automatically according to day

Tags: wordpress

I've a wordpress site which needs 7 different pages to show(**change the url automatically**) each day according to the current day. Page like www.example.com/monday,   www.example.com/tuesday,  www.example.com/wednesday, etc.

I've tried to change the **index.php** file by adding following code:

```
dow2post = array(Thursday => 2816, Friday => 2815, Saturday => 2841, Sunday => 2829, Monday => 2831, Tuesday => 2833, Wednesday => 2837); 

query_posts('page_id='.$dow2post[gmdate('l')]);
```

But it didn't work well. Can someone help to make this possible?